# Newton-Raphson Algorithm

Tags: c, algorithm

I'm to compile and run this program to solve an equation using the Newton-Raphson algorithm, but the number of iterations in the `do-while` loop is always `1`, which shouldn't be the case.

**Code**

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>

float fonc(float x){
   float result;
   result=2*(pow(x,3))-x-2;
   return result;
 }

float foncprime(float x){
   float result;
   result= 6*(pow(x,2))-1;
   return result;
}

int main(void)
{
   long double x1,x0;
   float eps;
   eps=0.5*pow(10,-4);
   x0=1;
   x1=1;
   int i=0;
   do
   {
      x0=x1;
      x1=x0-(fonc(x0)/foncprime(x0));
      i++;

   }
   while(x1-x0>eps);
   printf("%d",i);
}
```

Comment: Don't get in the habit of using `pow` to compute integer exponentiations. Use `x*x` for `x` squared, `x*x*x` for `x` cubed, and `5E-5` for `5/100000` (or `0.5E-4`, if you prefer.) `pow` is a lot slower and sometimes slightly less accurate.

Comment: @rici  I appreciate your advice will never forget it THANK YOU .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably check `while (fabs(x1-x0) > eps)`.

Answer (score 2):

You have assigned x1 to x0 just before the while loop test so the test is 0>eps which will always be false hence it exits the loop on the first iteration.

Comment: so what is the solution ? where can i assign it

Comment: I don't really know the method well enough, but assuming you want to test x1-x0 before assigning I would move the assignment to the start of the loop and change the initial x0=1 to x1=1 to ensure they start at the correct value.  Without fully understanding the maths this is a guess.

Comment: yes i just did that but it still not working and the result still the same

Comment: Try the fabs(x1-x0) as per other answers

Comment: It might also be a good idea to use double (or long double) throughout rather than mixing precision.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
   while(x1-x0>eps);
```

to:

```
   while(fabs(x1-x0)>eps);
```